# Is the Function() constructor not optimized by V8, like eval?

Tags: javascript, optimization, v8

We are trying a way to receive web components via WebSockets. Those components contains custom scripts and they should be run in a context inside the component.

In short, we have some script strings and want to run them.

Right now we are using `eval` for this, something like this:

```
function ctxEval(ctx, __script) {
    eval(__script);
    // return things with the ctx
}
```

and works as expected, but I'm reading that any function containing `eval` is not optimized by V8. I thought into converting it to `new Function()` like this:

```
new Function("ctx", __script)(ctx);
```

this way I can achieve the same as the `ctxEval` function above.

We know that `Function` is `eval()` because they act almost equally, but the question now is, until which point `Function` is `eval()`? Maybe because `Function()` has its own scope instead of the `eval` one which runs the code in the same scope, the function containing the `Function` call is actually optimized by V8. Also, [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) they talk about `eval` but not about `Function` constructor.

And another question implied in this one is, is the script that runs inside `Function()` optimized by V8?

Comment: Why do you need to use `eval` in the first place? Can't you run the JavaScript normally?

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/roll/src/bailout-reason.h#128

Comment: @Halcyon We receive the script as an string from a socket. Is not included in the main script connecting to the server.

Comment: @ponury-kostek So anonymous functions are not optimized? Didn't knew that

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález just set it to the `innerHTML` of a created script element and append it to the document. There's no need for `eval`.

Comment: @JaredSmith But, as I said, I need to context it. Filling a `script` in the head or body will run it in the global scope. All methods I can think of to have a reference to "the script body" when inserting it in a `script` node in the DOM are kinda hackish, so I prefer to use existing tools instead of hacking that way. Sometimes [eval is not that evil](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/).

Comment: By the way this is in the short time and while I was doing this the question went to my head. In the long time we are going to add a RequireJS thingy on top of WebSockets. This way we can create the `script` in the DOM, but right now we cannot without doing weird things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested this with this code

```
const adder = new Function('a', 'b', 'return b%2 ? a + b : b%3 ? a - b : b%5 ? b / a : a * b');
let b = 0, b2 = 0;
function _throw() {
    throw new Error('Ups');
}
function _catch() {
    try {_throw()} catch(e) {}
}
function printStatus(fn) {
    switch (%GetOptimizationStatus(fn)) {
        case 1: console.log(fn.name, "function is optimized"); break;
        case 2: console.log(fn.name, "function is not optimized"); break;
        case 3: console.log(fn.name, "function is always optimized"); break;
        case 4: console.log(fn.name, "function is never optimized"); break;
        case 6: console.log(fn.name, "function is maybe deoptimized"); break;
    }
}
eval('function evil(a,b) {return b%2 ? a + b : b%3 ? a - b : b%5 ? b / a : a * b}');
printStatus(adder);
printStatus(evil);
printStatus(_throw);
printStatus(_catch);
// Call the function
for(let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    b = adder(Math.random() * 10, b);
    b2 = evil(i, b2);
    _catch();
}
printStatus(adder);
printStatus(evil);
printStatus(_throw);
printStatus(_catch);
```

run command

```
$ node --allow-natives-syntax js.js
```

and the output is

```
anonymous function is not optimized
evil function is not optimized
_throw function is not optimized
_catch function is not optimized

anonymous function is optimized
evil function is optimized
_throw function is not optimized
_catch function is not optimized
```

**EDIT:**

I modified this test code to check other bailots and im realy surprised because it looks that `eval` is also optimized :>

**EDIT 2:**

After some additional research I found this https://blog.sqreen.io/optimize-your-node-app-by-simply-upgrading-node-js/

Comment: Kinda good. So is optimized after running it. Need to test the parent function containing the `new Function` call.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález check new interesting results after some additional tests

Comment: Yes, was doing some tests too. I have a bit outdated node and seems that `eval` and `Function` are optimized different, so I think that yes, altough they evaluate strings, they work different when optimizing them: https://gist.github.com/Llorx/975779da3919d3777877ca5b748e1a15

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález
I've run your code ( and the code of ponury-kostek as well)  on node v8.2.1 (later on with v8.7.0)
and I got some optimization code which out of the range (like 17, and 49)

When looking at v8 source is doesn't describe such status codes (but rather multiplications of 2: 1, 2, 4,  8 to 2024).
Any ideas?
[v8 OptimizationStatus](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/217de927fbe9dfd356f49d5ba8c1145d7b161f1f/src/runtime/runtime.h)

Comment: @yuval.bl If the source code don't says nothing then I can't help :-/ Maybe you should make a question here with an example code for everyone to test.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález
Here is my code, tested on node v8.2.1 and  8.7.0.
see comment at the bottom of the file
https://gist.github.com/yuvalbl/2f9032d71a69288e2d21e93ae0055f3c
I'll open a new question about these results as well.

Comment: see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749742/what-happens-to-v8-status-code-on-optimization-function-run)

Comment: @yuval.bl Oh, I see you had a reply already. They are correct. They are bit masks.